# ListView.builder not working

Tags: dart, flutter

While trying to implement the [flutter-firebase](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#8), the `ListView.builder` failed to be displayed!

Note, when I try displaying the first element without `ListView.builder` it works fine, i.e. the error is only in something related to this block of code:

```
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
    itemExtent: 25.0,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
    return Text(" ${ds['name']} ${ds['vote']}");
});
```

My full code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp(
  textInput: Text("Text Widget"),
));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget textInput;
  MyApp({this.textInput});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool checkBoxValue = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: new Center(
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    widget.textInput,
                    Checkbox(
                        value: checkBoxValue,
                        onChanged: (bool newValue){
                          setState(() {
                            checkBoxValue = newValue;
                          });
                        }
                    ),
                    StreamBuilder(
                        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('baby').snapshots(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');

                           //   DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[0];
                           //   return new Text(" ${ds['name']} ${ds['vote']}");

                          // When i try to replace the above code by the below it fails!
                               return ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                                itemExtent: 25.0,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                                return Text(" ${ds['name']} ${ds['vote']}");
                              });
                           // End of the ListView builder that fails!

                        }),
                  ],
                ))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The error I got is:

> Performing hot reload...
>   I/flutter ( 9119): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 9119): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
>   I/flutter ( 9119): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
>   I/flutter ( 9119): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
>   I/flutter ( 9119): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
>   I/flutter ( 9119): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
>   I/flutter ( 9119): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
>   I/flutter ( 9119): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
>   I/flutter ( 9119): 
>   I/flutter ( 9119): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #0      RenderViewport.performResize. (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:985:15)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #1      RenderViewport.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1038:6)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1555:9)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #3      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #5      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #7      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #9      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #11     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #13     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #15     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #19     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:738:15)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #21     RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:381:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #23     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:141:11)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #24     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:399:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #25     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:211:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #26     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:355:14)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #28     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #30     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #31     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1143:11)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #33     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:199:11)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #35     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #37     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #39     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #41     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #43     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #45     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #47     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #48     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #49     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #50     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2831:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #52     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:520:15)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #54     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #56     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #58     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #60     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #62     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #64     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:109:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #65     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #66     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:125:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #67     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1445:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #68     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:709:18)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #69     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:270:19)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #70     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:627:13)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #71     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:208:5)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #72     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #73     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #74     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame. (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:751:7)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #76     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #77     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): #78     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): (elided one frame from package dart:async)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): 
>   I/flutter ( 9119): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   RenderViewport#a2532 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   creator: Viewport ← _ScrollableScope ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#363cb] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#08fb7] ←
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   _ExcludableScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#8d2f7] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← RepaintBoundary ←
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   NotificationListener ← ⋯
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   parentData:  (can use size)
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=384.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   size: MISSING
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   axisDirection: down
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   crossAxisDirection: right
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#45c18(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null,
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#d36b9,
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   ScrollDirection.idle)
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   anchor: 0.0
>   I/flutter ( 9119): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   RenderSliverPadding#9ca2b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119):     RenderSliverFixedExtentList#1cb4d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119):       RenderRepaintBoundary#8c403 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119):         RenderParagraph#c05e3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#a2532 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#a2532 NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#cfad6 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#2fd15 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#0da92 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#588c9 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderExcludableScrollSemantics#ad008 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#1e512 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#ab136 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#e6025 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
>   Reloaded 1 of 394 libraries in 1,363ms.
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#e6025 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT

Comment: Can you include the error ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet just added.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the real problem, it was at:

```
   return ListView.builder(
         itemExtent: 25.0 . // this made the limitation
)
```

I should remove the `itemExtent`, so the list became expandable by default :)

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with this. At most removing `itemExtent` will fix an overflow exception. Not a `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height`.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your `StreamBuilder` into an `Expanded`. As it's inside a `Column`

Comment: How can I use `Card` as `Child` instead of the `Text`, can you help with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002111/adding-card-to-listview

Answer (score 1):

You can add the property `shrinkWrap: true` as indicated in your error message:

```
return ListView.builder(
   shrinkWrap: true,
   ...
)
```