# Adding Card to ListView

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to get list of [Cards](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Card-class.html), and trying using the `Expanded` widget, but got `overflow` error

My code:

```
new Expanded(
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('baby').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                itemExtent: 25.0,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                  return //Text(" ${ds['name']} ${ds['vote']}");
                    Card(
                      child: Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            const ListTile(
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
                              title: const Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
                              subtitle: const Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
                            ),
                            new ButtonTheme.bar( // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
                              child: ButtonBar(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                   FlatButton(
                                    child: const Text('BUY TICKETS'),
                                    onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                                  ),
                                   FlatButton(
                                    child: const Text('LISTEN'),
                                    onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                    ),
                    );
                });
          })),
```

The error I got is: `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.`

Full error:

> Performing hot reload...
>   I/flutter ( 9119): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 9119): The following assertion was thrown building DefaultTextStyle(debugLabel: (englishLike
>   I/flutter ( 9119): body1).merge(blackMountainView body1), inherit: false, color: Color(0xdd000000), family: Roboto,
>   I/flutter ( 9119): size: 14.0, weight: 400, baseline: alphabetic, decoration: TextDecoration.none, softWrap: wrapping
>   I/flutter ( 9119): at box width, overflow: clip):
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Expanded widgets must be placed directly inside Flex widgets.
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Expanded(no depth, flex: 1, dirty) has a Flex ancestor, but there are other widgets between them:
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#93e52 ink renderer]
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - CustomPaint
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - PhysicalShape(clipper: ShapeBorderClipper, elevation: 1.0, color: Color(0xffffffff), shadowColor:
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   Color(0xff000000))
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0))
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - Semantics(container: true, properties: SemanticsProperties, label: null, value: null, hint: null)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - RepaintBoundary-[<0>]
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - KeepAlive(keepAlive: false)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - SliverFixedExtentList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate#b334e(estimated child count: 3))
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0))
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - Viewport(axisDirection: down, anchor: 0.0, offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#bebad(offset:
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   0.0, range: 0.0..0.0, viewport: 380.0, ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics ->
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   ClampingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#7b3a8, ScrollDirection.idle))
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#4c7f9](ignoring: false, ignoringSemantics: false)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, label: null, value: null, hint: null)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - Listener(listeners: [down], behavior: opaque)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - _GestureSemantics
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - _ExcludableScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#22165]
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - RepaintBoundary
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - CustomPaint
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - RepaintBoundary
>   I/flutter ( 9119): - Expanded(flex: 1) (this is a different Expanded than the one with the problem)
>   I/flutter ( 9119): These widgets cannot come between a Expanded and its Flex.
>   I/flutter ( 9119): The ownership chain for the parent of the offending Expanded was:
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#93e52 ink renderer] ←
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   NotificationListener ← CustomPaint ← _ShapeBorderPaint ← PhysicalShape
>   I/flutter ( 9119):   ← _MaterialInterior ← Material ← Padding ← ⋯
>   I/flutter ( 9119): 
>   ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>   I/chatty  ( 9119): uid=10096(com.example.flutterapp) Thread-3 identical 3 lines
>   I/flutter ( 9119): Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

**UPDATE**
Here is the output screen I got:

[image]

If I removed the `Expanded` the output became like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need that expanded there.

Comment: @Bostrot without the expanded it is worst :(

Comment: The error is actually `Expanded widgets must be placed directly inside Flex widgets.` Flex widgets are like Row, Column, Flex, etc.

Comment: @JacobPhillips I updated my question with what I see in the screen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out, the whole problem was in using `itemExtent: 25.0,` at `ListView.builder` by removing it, everything became expandable by default and run smoothly.

While searching for the solution, I came across [this](https://flutterbyexample.com/list-view-and-builder-methods/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45670718/2441637) and [this](https://flutter.io/cookbook/lists/long-lists/), that helped me rebuilding the app in a cleaner code, below it is for who is interested:

`main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'BabyModel.dart';
import 'BabyCard.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp(
  textInput: Text("Text Widget"),
));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget textInput;
  MyApp({this.textInput});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool checkBoxValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('baby').snapshots(),
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        var documents = snapshot.data?.documents ?? [];
        var baby =
        documents.map((snapshot) => BabyData.from(snapshot)).toList();
        return BabyPage(baby);
      },
    );
  }
}

class BabyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<BabyData> allBaby;

  BabyPage(this.allBaby);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return BabyPageState();
  }
}


class BabyPageState extends State<BabyPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  //  var filteredBaby = widget.allFish.where((BabyData data) {
  //    data.name = 'Dana';
  //  }).toList();

    return MaterialApp(
        home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: widget.allBaby.length,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return BabyCard(widget.allBaby[index]);
            })
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

`BabyModel.dart`:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class BabyData {
  final DocumentReference reference;
  String name;
  int vote;

  BabyData.data(this.reference,
      [this.name,
        this.vote]) {
    // Set these rather than using the default value because Firebase returns
    // null if the value is not specified.
    this.name ??= 'Frank';
    this.vote ??= 7;
  }

  factory BabyData.from(DocumentSnapshot document) => BabyData.data(
      document.reference,
      document.data['name'],
      document.data['vote']);

  void save() {
    reference.setData(toMap());
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'vote': vote,
    };
  }
}
```

`BabyCard.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'BabyModel.dart';

class BabyCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final BabyData baby;

  BabyCard(this.baby);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return BabyCardState(baby);
  }
}

class BabyCardState extends State<BabyCard> {
  BabyData baby;
  String renderUrl;

  BabyCardState(this.baby);

  Widget get babyCard {
    return
      new Card(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
              title: Text('The ${baby.name} is having:'),
              subtitle: Text('${baby.vote} Votes.'),
            ),
            new ButtonTheme.bar( // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
              child: new ButtonBar(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                    child: const Text('Thumb up'),
                    onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                  ),
                  new FlatButton(
                    child: const Text('Thumb down'),
                    onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                  )]))]));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
          child:  babyCard,
        );
  }
}
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: @CrsCaballero all the code I usd is appearing above

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the print of mobile screen in your question ?

I put your code and without expanded widget and its perfect,
what you want to change?

[image: Print mobile]

Comment: I updated my question with what I see in the screen. did you connected your app to firebase!